# Remapping Esc to Tab in Spacemacs

Tags: shell, spacemacs

I'm accustomed to remapping Esc to Tab in Vim. In Spacemacs this can be done with:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map [tab] 'evil-normal-state)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map [tab] 'evil-normal-state)
```

in `dotspacemacs/config` in `.spacemacs`. This leaves me with the option of pressing `C-i` when `Tab` is really needed (quite rarely in my case).

However, shells in Spacemacs are also run in vi-mode, and there `Tab` key is really convenient for completion, obviously.

How can i either

- Run shells in emacs-mode
- or disable `Tab` remapping in shells while retaining it elsewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that i simply did not enable Spacemacs's own `shell` layer. This is what i have now in `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`:

```
(shell :variables
             shell-default-height 30
             shell-default-position 'bottom
             shell-default-shell 'multi-term)
```

With this configuration, `Tab` works as `Tab`, even when though it's remapped to `Esc` in my configuration as shown in the question. Which seems nice.